# Bash: how to read a multiple lines into another file, while replacing delims and truncating after token $n

Tags: bash, csv, echo

What I'm trying to do is change the format of one particular file into another:

input.csv:

```
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6
```

output.txt:

```
value2:value3
```

I can almost do this using the following, but it all gets read out on the same line, rather than out to multiple:

```
output=$(while IFS="," read -r value1 value2 value3 remainder; do echo $value2:$value3 ; done < "input.csv")
echo $output > output.txt
```

solved my own issue by adding \ at the end of the echo string

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F',' '{printf "%s:%s\n", $2, $3}' file.csv
```

Printing comma separated second and third column with `:` as the separator.

**Example:**

```
% awk -F',' '{printf "%s:%s\n", $2, $3}' <<<'value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6'
value2:value3
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding a backslash "\" to the end of the echo string

Answer (score 0):

If the `output` variable is not needed for anything else you can save a pid and some grief by removing the command substitution

```
while IFS=',' read -r value1 value2 value3 remainder; do
  echo "$value2:$value3"
done
```

A more robust and general way to process csv input is to use awk as shown at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

```
awk 'BEGIN {FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; OFS=":"} {print $2,$3}'
```